# Не перезагружать открытое Activity при открытии из notification

Tags: android, xamarin.android

В [моем приложении](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.my_station) используется лишь одно Activiy-MainActivity с картой, когда приложении в фоне и пользователь приближается к нужному ему месту, ему приходит уведомление

По нажатию на уведомление мне нужно открыть последнее использующееся activiy, то есть не перезагружать MainActivity

сейчас я использую простой `Intent`

```
 var Intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        Intent.PutExtra("some_data", 1);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(Intent);
 .....
```

Но такая работа мне не подходит.

Как я могу передать в Intent именно ту активность из который отправляется Notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вывести ваше приложение на передний план, не вызывая новых активити используйте этот метод.

```
public static Intent newLauncherIntent(final Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    return intent;
}
```

Интент, созданный этим методом, не запускает новую активити, если приложение запущено, даже если оно имеет этот флаг.